# play youtube videos permission

Tags: flutter, youtube, youtube-player-flutter

I’m using youtube_player in my app to play videos, some of which I own and some I don’t. I’m wondering if this goes against Play Store rules and if so, how can I incorporate YouTube videos in my app without breaking any rules?